# Como puedo crear una aplicación no listada en App Store?

Tags: ios, certificado-apple

Segun estuve investigando y se puede crear una aplicación no listada en App Store, pero no se muy bien como, segun lo que encontre los pasos seria los siguentes

- Compilar la App de Asistencias con su certificado de distribución.
- Publicar la aplicación en App Store. (Se requiere un certificado especial?)
- Enviar la aplicación a App Review.
- Generar la solicitud para crear una aplicación no listada.
- Una vez aceptada, compartir el enlace de la aplicación.

No se si hay algun otro paso que deba tomar en cuanta para realizar este proceso, me apoyarian en mucho para seguir con esta publicación

Comment: Tienes que tener cuenta en AppleDeveloper, tienes que generar un ID de empresa o segun sea el caso para poder publicar una App. 

Te dejo el enlace para que te orientes

https://developer.apple.com/help/account/

Comment: La cuenta de Apple developer ya la tengo creada al igual que la membresia, pero si o si tengo que tener mi ID de empresa?

Comment: En una oportunidad me toco hacer ese proceso, comprendo que si porque con ese ID Apple Confirma con una patente o el registro de tu ubicación de la empresa por así decirlo. Imagino que tendrán alguna otra opción, podrías en tu cuenta solicitar comunicarte con ellos. Tienen un apartado de soporte, solo es que selecciones la opción correcta. Ya que todo es mediante email.

Hay un apartado que indica como obtener tu ID o solicitarlo

Comment: Quieres que la app esté en la app store pero que no la vea nadie? Quédate tranquilo, no creo que un millón de personas la descargue de un día al otro. Y sino, tal vez haya algo como en Android, que se pueden cargar aplicaciones para que ciertas personas la prueben.

Comment: @dr pero para obtener este ID, es antes de subir mi aplicación?

Comment: @Mateo en este caso escuche que se puede por medio del ipa, pero ya intente y no me deja, me aparece que no se puede instalar debido a que no se puede verificar, pero se puede crear alguna credencial para eso?